# Sequence of Polynomials and Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, derivatives

Using the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem I need to prove that if $f$ has $k$ continuous derivatives in $[a,b]$, then exists a sequence of polynomials {$P_n$} such that {$P_n$} converges uniformly to $f$ in $[a,b]$, {$P'_n$} converges uniformly to $f'$ in $[a,b]$, ... ,  {$P_n^{(k)}$} converges uniformly to ${f^{(k)}}$ in $[a,b]$.

To prove that exists a sequence that converges uniformly to the function it's the easy thing, and exists a different sequence of polynomials that converge uniformly to each derivative, but I really don't have any idea how to construct the sequence such that all the derivatives converge uniformly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose we started with a sequence of polynomials $\{g_n\}$ that converges to $f'$.  How could we find a sequence $G_n$, with $G_n' = g_n$, such that $\{G_n\}$ converges to $f$?

Perhaps we could set $G_n = \int_a^x g_n(t)\,dt+ C$ for the "right" choice of $C \in \Bbb R$.  How do we choose $C$? How do we guarantee that the result converges as desired?

**Note:** for a sequence $\{g_n\}$ converging to $g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, we can indeed state that
$$
\int_a^x g_n(t)\,dt \to \int_a^x g(t)\,dt
$$ 
uniformly.  If you've never seen this before, you should try to prove it.